# MariaDB SQL Syntax Error - "right syntax to use near 'order("

Tags: php, mysqli

> QUERY Failed! You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(product_id,customer_name,total_bill,quantity)VALUES(1,'taha khan',5368,22)' at line 1

```php
<?php 
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {   
        $product = $_POST['product_id'];
        $customer_name = $_POST['customer'];
        $qty = $_POST['qty'];
        $product_cost = $_POST['product_cost'];
        $total_bill = $product_cost * $qty;

        $result = "INSERT INTO order(product_id,customer_name,total_bill,quantity)VALUES($product,'$customer_name',$total_bill,$qty)";
        $query = query($result);

        confirmQuery($query);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot name your table `order` and use it like that. That is a [reserved keyword](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/).

That being said, you **can** still use that name if you insist by doing:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (product_id...
```

The backticks will allow it to work. My recommendation would be to name your table `orders` instead to avoid conflicts in queries.

---

It is important for me to also note that your query is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should **NEVER** take raw input and put it straight into your database. There is nothing stopping me from posting a fragment of a SQL query in the `customer` field and stealing data.

Take the time to learn how to use prepared statements, it will be extremely beneficial: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php